# Remove activity from stack, create new instance on Top

Tags: android, android-activity

My activity flow is like this

A -> B -> C -> B

When I launch B from C, the back stack should be re-ordered to:

A -> C -> B

I'm using FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT but that re-uses instance from stack, I don't need previous state (I need to call onCreate again.)

Update: **Why I need it (Use case)**

User navigates from A -> B (changes something here) -> C

Opens up Drawer Navigation on C and launches B.
B should be launched with initial state.

Comment: Weird scenario but some could help you on this if you provide the actual use case...

Comment: Why don't you stick with FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT and just re-initialize the views/fragments/data that you care about onResume()? It seems like a waste of CPU to create a whole new Activity if it's just some data that was invalidated.

Comment: @Matt that would be tedious, application has 30 activities, all activities follow this flow

Comment: I don't know how your app looks, but can't you create an abstract BaseActivity or something that takes care of this for you?

Comment: @Matt isn't it tedious to re-initialize the view/etc every time activity is paused/resumed?

Answer (score 0):

Use `FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT` and add an extra to the `Intent`, like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityB.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
intent.putExtra("reinitialize", true);
startActivity(intent);
```

Then, in `ActivityB` do this to recreate the activity when it is brought to the front:

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    if (intent.hasExtra("reinitialize")) {
        // We need to recreate this activity
        Intent launchIntent = new Intent(this, this.getClass());
        startActivity(launchIntent);
        finish();
    }
}
```